# How to use XMLHttpRequest in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xmlhttprequest, webrequest

I'm creating easy to use [kannada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada) comic reader on mac for my cousins. I'm able to pull the comic pages, but lot of meta content exchanged webpage and server using `XMLHttpRequest`.

I'm finding difficulties use `XMLHttpRequest`, could anyone tell me how can I use it?

Comment: Are you trying to do the same thing as XMLHttpRequest from Cocoa code, or are you trying to do one in JavaScript inside of a WebView?

Comment: @Peter I'm trying to do it in Cocoa code, I want to bind the data to the combobox...

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a simple XMLHttpRequest is to [create a data object from a URL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:).

For more advanced requests (e.g., custom headers, request methods that aren't GET), you'll need to use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/). You should probably do that anyway; your application will be more robust and more responsive for it.

Comment: Keep in mind dataWithContentsOfURL: is synchronous and will result in a blocking UI during the request. Use NSURLConnection for asynchronous requests.

Comment: Yup. Uncareful use of `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a good way to make a slow UI and frustrate the user. When the URL isn't local, you generally should use NSURLConnection instead.